# NodeJS: Don't wait for function return

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm currently starting with NodeJS and I want to run the Same function multiple times at once with different Arguments, but I am not sure how.
From my current experience NodeJS/JavaScript in general doesn't wait for a function to return, but in my case it does which really confuses me.

My current code looks something like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
start=function(values){
    max=5
    started=0
    finished=0
    maxReachedBefore=false
    finishedStarting=false
    result=[]
    
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(!finishedStarting){
            if((started-finished)>= max) {
                if(!maxReachedBefore){
                    console.log("Max Reached!")
                    maxReachedBefore=true
                }
                return;
            }
            maxReachedBefore=false
            getValue(values[started])
            console.log("Started getValue")
            started++
        } else {
            if (started<=finished){
                clearInterval(interval)
                console.log("Finished!")
            }
        }
        
    },10)
}

getValue=function(value){
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("get","MY_WEBSITE_HERE.COM/"+value, false)
    request.send()
    result=result.concat(request.responseText)
    console.log("Finished getValue")
    finished++
}

start(["a","medium","sized","list","of","values","that","i","want","to","get","the","corresponding","values","to"])
```

Now I would expect this to Keep Starting getValue with the different values while max is not reached -> getValue is running less than 6 times, but this isn't the case. getValue is started One-by-One, the next one only starting after the last one finished.

Can someone explain why this is happening / Help me change it?

Please have mercy, I'm relatively new to NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a synchronous request to server. So the function will wait for the response from the server.

```
request.open("get","MY_WEBSITE_HERE.COM/"+value, false)
```

The last parameter `boolean` specifies whether the call is sync or async.

```
request.open("get","MY_WEBSITE_HERE.COM/"+value, true)
```

This will send asynchronous call, and in the callback function add the console statements of finished get value.

```
var finished = 0;
var result=[];
 start=function(values){
 max=5
 started=0    
 maxReachedBefore=false
 finishedStarting=false

  interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(!finishedStarting){
        if((started-finished)>= max) {
            if(!maxReachedBefore){
                console.log("Max Reached!")
                maxReachedBefore=true; 
                finishedStarting = true;
            }
            return;
        }
        maxReachedBefore=false; 
        console.log("Started getValue " + values[started]);

        getValue(values[started]); 
        started++;

    } else {
        if (started<=finished){
            clearInterval(interval)
            console.log("Finished!")
        }
    }

  },10);
}

getValue=function(value){
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("get","MY_WEBSITE_HERE.COM/"+value, true); 

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
       result=result.concat(request.responseText);
       console.log("Finished getValue " + value)
       finished++;
     }
    };
   request.send();
   console.log("request sent");
}
```